# MIPS How can I write a tester program to test my macro?

Tags: assembly, macros, bit-manipulation, mips

I am working a macro to extract nth bit. I wonder how to pass value and test this macro?

```
.macro extract_nth_bit($regD, $regS, $regT)
srl $regS, $regS, $regT
and $regD, $regS, 1
# regD contains bit position ( will contain 0x0 or 0x1 depending on nth bit being 0 or 1
# regS is the bit pattern ( source bit pattern )
# regT will be 0x0 or 0x1 ( bit position n (0-31)
.end_macro
```

Comment: If `$regT` is a constant (e.g. you invoke with `extract_nth_bit($t0,$t1,1)`), then `srl` is correct. If it is a register (e.g. `extract_nth_bit($t0,$t1,$t2)`), you will need to use `srlv` instead

Comment: @CraigEstey. I see. Thank you for pointing out!